# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() error found in helpers/BaseArrayHelper.php when using yii2 php5 apache

Tags: php-5.6, linux-mint

I got problem **Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/vagrant/www/.../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/helpers/BaseArrayHelper.php on line 121** when want to surf my local by using apache as my server. All environment have been set up in vagrant with using php5.5.9.

Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Return empty array in config files which are empty.
suppose your params-local.php have only opening php tag then

Replace

with

```
<?php
    return [
    ];
```